# How to handle ImgData in C#?

Tags: c#, gaussian, convolution, iplimage

I'm trying to implement an retinex filter following the one posted [here](http://blog.csdn.net/onezeros/article/details/6342661). At the beginning he defines:

```
#define pc(image, x, y, c) image->imageData[(image->widthStep * y) + (image->nChannels * x) + c]
```

and when doing the gaussian convolution he is using it as:

```
v1 += kernel[k] * (unsigned char)pc(temp, i, source, 0);
```

and later:

```
pc(img, i, j, 0) = (char)int2smallint(v1);
```

I'm not able to translate this to C#, neither do I understand what he's doing exactly. There are no unsigned chars in C# and also the way he access the image data is completely different. So, what is the best way to implement this in C#?

Comment: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f074e0dd-865c-fd5f-ba0a-80e336a0eaea.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved it. This:

```
v1 += kernel[k] * (unsigned char)pc(temp, i, source, 0);
```

is translated to:

```
IntPtr ptr = img.ImageData;
v1 += kernel[k] * Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, (i * img.WidthStep) + (source * img.NChannels) + 0);
```

Marshal is the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> There are no unsigned chars in C#

Byte. Char in C/C++ is a byte in C#, and there are bytes in C# ;)

> also the way he access the image data is completely different.

Hardly. ImageData is a bitmap of some type and he does simple bitmap stuff via array syntax. THis is doable in C# too - grab the bitmap or whatever interim form he uses and put it into a byte array. Now without understanding what he does that is a lost cause. I am also not sure I Woudl not blow that up into a DirectX surface and write a filter for that;)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply! I understand now what he is doing, but i'm still not able to access each pixel from the image. What would be the equivalent in C# for: myimage.imageData[3*(y*myimage.width+x)+0] = 100; for the red channel for example?

Comment: Depends how the image looks like in bitmap form - which you say nothing about.

Comment: myimage is an IplImage with 3 channels. myimage.ImageData does exist, but it returns an Intptr and doesn't allow indexing...